# How to remove empty list in pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, list

**I am redaing data from csv**
I have a dataframe like this:

```
product_title   variatons_color          
T-shirt          ['yellow','ornage'] 
T-shirt          []
T-shirt          ['blue','green']
```

my expected dataframe will be look like this

```
product_title   variatons_color          
T-shirt          ['yellow','ornage'] 
T-shirt         
T-shirt          ['blue','green']
```

I want to remove empty list. How to do that in pandas?

**update1**
I applied Scott **Boston,Ynjxsjmh** and **BENY** solution. All solution filling None value for all of my row but I need to fill None value for only my empty list.
when I run `type(df.loc[0,'variations_color'])` returning `str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check assign with bool check

```
df.loc[~df['variatons_color'].astype(bool),'variatons_color'] = ''
```

Update

```
df.loc[df['variatons_color'].eq('[]'),'variatons_color'] = ''
```

Comment: BENY it's also remove all list. I want to set value none only for empty list

Comment: @boyenec 1st make sure your list is list, [] will return False after astype bool, none empty list will return True

Comment: BENY  I have list `['yellow','ornage'] ` like this. I haven't list in list.

Comment: @boyenec print ['yellow','ornage']  or '['yellow','ornage'] '?

Comment: BENY it's actual python list ['yellow','ornage'] not '['yellow','ornage'] '

Comment: BENY any update???

Comment: @boyenec use this df = pd.DataFrame({'product_title':['T-shirt']*3,
                   'variatons_color':[['yellow', 'orange'],[],['blue', 'green']]}) as df , and try all the solution

Comment: I can't use this dataframe because I am reading data from csv

Comment: @boyenec check the update

Comment: still now it's filling None value for all row. see the screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mkDocXCVQEzEUK2md3MIIHFgBH9v-YiY/view?usp=sharing I am not understanding instead of filling None value only for emty list why it's filling None value for all list  those are not empty.

Comment: your second solution working but is it possible to add multiple column ?

Comment: @boyenec `df = df.mask(df.eq('[]'),'')`

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```py
df['variatons_color'] = df['variatons_color'].apply(lambda lst: lst if len(lst) else '')
```

```
print(df)

  product_title   variatons_color
0       T-shirt  [yellow, ornage]
1       T-shirt
2       T-shirt     [blue, green]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your code also remove the list those are not empty list. Actually your code removing all of my list.  I need to fill None only for my empty list

Comment: Ynjxsjmh any update???

Comment: @boyenec What's the result of your `df.loc[0, 'variatons_color'].tolist()`?

Comment: `str' object has no attribute 'tolist'`

Comment: @boyenec You can try `df['variatons_color'] = df['variatons_color'].apply(pd.eval)` to convert string list to real list first.

Answer (score 2):

Just `apply` `len`:

```
df.loc[df['variations_color'].apply(len) == 0, 'variations_color'] = ''
```

or

```
df.loc[df['variations_color'].apply(len) == 0, 'variations_color'] =  np.nan
```

Output:

```
  product_title  variations_color
0       T-shirt  [yellow, orange]
1       T-shirt               NaN
2       T-shirt     [blue, green]
```

given df,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'product_title':['T-shirt']*3,
                   'variations_color':[['yellow', 'orange'],[],['blue', 'green']]})
```

---

However, if your datafame structure is like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'product_title':['T-shirt']*3,
                   'variations_color':['[yellow, orange]','[]','[blue, green]']})
```

Then, you can use the following:

```
df.loc[df['variations_color'] == '[]', 'variations_color'] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
  product_title  variations_color
0       T-shirt  [yellow, orange]
1       T-shirt               NaN
2       T-shirt     [blue, green]
```

---

Note the difference in the first example

`type(df.loc[0,'variations_color'])` returns a list

And, the second returns str.  The string representation of the dataframe are identical, so you can't tell just by looking at it when printing.  It is always important in python to know what kind (datatype) of the object you're working with.

Comment: cott Boston it's filling `value == ' '`  for every row. I need to fill `value == ' ' ` for only empty list

Comment: also getting error `NameError: name 'np' is not defined` when tried your second code

Comment: np is numpy library ... np.nan is the NaN object(None). `import numpy as np` when you import pandas.

Comment: Is your variatons_color a true list object or a string?    How to tell, `type(df.loc[0,'variations_color'])`?

Comment: see the screenshot1  for your second part of  code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UfN_HIJueKNGtaSNgivJPQblfPwsD1m7/view?usp=sharing still now  not working

Comment: What does type above command return?

Comment: Scott Boston it's returning `str`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245207/discussion-between-boyenec-and-scott-boston).

Comment: Scott Boston any update ???

Comment: Ah.. str that's you problem.   This is not a true list. Try this: `df.loc[df['variations_color'] == '[]', 'variations_color'] = np.nan`

Comment: Your dataframe code can be simulated like this:
`df = pd.DataFrame({'product_title':['T-shirt']*3,
                   'variations_color':['[yellow, orange]','[]','[blue, green]']})`

Comment: See update in [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72449586/6361531).

Comment: your second solution working but can I add multiple row like this ????`df.loc[df['column1','column2'] == '[]',['column1','column2']] = np.nan`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'product_title':['T-shirt']*3,
                   'variations_color':[['yellow', 'orange'],[],['blue', 'green']]})
df['variations_color'] = df['variations_color'].apply(lambda x: None if any(eval(str(x))) == False else x)
df
```

Comment: Nothing happening and getting my original dataframe result

Comment: getting error `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Answer (score 0):

Look here!

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''
product_title   variatons_color          
T-shirt          ['yellow','ornage'] 
T-shirt          []
T-shirt          ['blue','green']
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df.variatons_color = df.variatons_color.apply(eval)
df
'''
  product_title   variatons_color
0       T-shirt  [yellow, ornage]
1       T-shirt                []
2       T-shirt     [blue, green]
'''



type(df.iat[0, 1])
# list


df.mask(df.applymap(len) == 0, None)
'''
  product_title   variatons_color
0       T-shirt  [yellow, ornage]
1       T-shirt              None
2       T-shirt     [blue, green]
'''
```

Done!